# Why is "ORDER BY" breaking my query?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, visual-studio-2010

I'm using the code below to grab a list of companies from my database and load them into a list view. It's working great.

```
conn.Open();
string pricesqry = "SELECT company, url FROM companies";
SqlCommand pricescmd = new SqlCommand(pricesqry, conn);
SqlDataReader pricesreader = pricescmd.ExecuteReader();

while (pricesreader.Read())
{
    ListViewItem company = new ListViewItem(pricesreader["company"].ToString());
    company.SubItems.Add(pricesreader["url"].ToString());
    company.SubItems.Add("Blank for now..");

    pricesList.Items.Add(company);
}
conn.Close();
```

However, if I wanted to alphabetize my list by company names, by changing my select query to this:

```
string pricesqry = "SELECT company, url FROM companies ORDER BY company";
```

No data is loaded into the listview. Remove the order by section and the data appears again. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: if you execute that query in Sql Management Studio do you get results?

Comment: Do you have any `NULL`s on the column `company`?

Comment: What's the type of `company`?

Comment: Do you have a try...catch around the code in question?  Is it possible your query is timing out with the ORDER BY in there and you are swallowing the error in a try...catch?

Comment: @minitech - Column was of type 'Text'. Changed it to Varchar and it's working as I expected. Newbie mistake. :-) Thanks for drawing my attention to column types.

Comment: Yeah, columns of type ntext, text, image, geography, geometry, and xml cannot be used in an ORDER BY clause. ;-)

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188385.aspx, Limitations and Restrictions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Credit goes to Minitech.

My 'Company' column type was set to Text. Changed to varchar and it's now working as I expected.

Answer (score 0):

In case you might have `NULL`'s in database it would be better to get the values from reader like this:

Assuming company and url is a string.

```
ListViewItem company = new ListViewItem(Convert.IsDBNull(pricesreader.GetOrdinal("company")) ? null : pricesreader.GetString(pricesreader.GetOrdinal("company")));

company.SubItems.Add(Convert.IsDBNull(pricesreader.GetOrdinal("url")) ? null : pricesreader.GetString(pricesreader.GetOrdinal("url")));
```

hope this helps.